# Trouble with identifying a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I was reading Michael Artin's Algebra and ran into trouble in the chapter on commutative rings. Specifically, the proof of assertion b) in lemma 11.8.7:
[image]

How can we identify $\Bbb C$ as a subring of $\mathcal F$? And what is this map $\Bbb C\to \mathcal F$ precisely? Just dropping the $a_kx^k$ parts of the polynomial?

Comment: What is M in the statement of $(b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a homomorphism $i:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ which takes a complex number and considers it as a constant polynomial.  The map $\mathbb{C}\to\mathcal{F}$ is just the composition of $\pi$ and $i$.  So you take a complex number, think of it as a constant polynomial, and then take the the coset of that constant polynomial in the quotient $\mathcal{F}=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/M$.  This map is injective, because $M$ does not contain any nonzero constant polynomials (if it did, then $M$ would be all of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ since any nonzero constant is a unit).  So the image of this map is a subring of $\mathcal{F}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!